# How can I make every first row from my Id?

Tags: sql-server, database

This is my image of database result:

[image]

Comment: every first line of column id ? can you clarify a little more ?

Comment: please check out my link which i just posted.  
 click on:-
This is How my data are but i want every first line of column Id.

Comment: Plz edit your question via adding desired result section in code format.

Comment: i did that and still couldn't figure out what you actually want, every first line of column id , do you want the whole row of a certain id ?

Comment: @DeepJadia can you please confirm whether posted answers are useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Row_number you can get first row of your ID

```
Select * from (
        Select *,
    Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN 
From Your Table )T 
Where T.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Id,Label,Score,Flag,AutoGenId from (
   Select *,
   Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN
From [VisionApiResponseData] )T
Where T.RN = 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!